# Ubuntu connected external keyboard working different as primary

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 on Omen 15.
The laptop keyboard working fine.
I connected a wireless Sandstrom keyboard, but it is not working like the primary one.
For example the F1-12 buttons works like when you press fn or activated it.
So how can I set the external connect keyboard to treat as the primary one with same keys and functions?